# Ruby on Rails Active Record Query Interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following:

`models/like.rb`:

```
class Like
    belongs_to :post
end
```

`models/post.rb`:

```
class Post
    has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy

    def self.popular
       Like.group(:post_id).count << ??? 
    end
end
```

I would like to make a scope that returns the most popular posts: posts with more than 20 likes, but I don't know how to make the conditional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use counter_cache to do this. You will have to create an extra column, but it is more performatic when SELECTing.

`models/like.rb`

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post, counter_cache: true
end
```

`models/post.rb`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy

  def self.popular
    where('likes_count > 20').order('likes_count DESC')
  end
end
```

Then create the migration:

```
class AddLikesToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :likes_count, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

And populate `likes_count` for your current Posts on `rails console` (only needed if you already have some created posts):

```
Post.find_each { |post| Post.reset_counters(post.id, :likes) }
```

After this, each time you create a new Like, the counter will be automatically incremented.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's the answer!